# How do I keep visual studio 2019 files/tabs open when I close the program?

Tags: visual-studio, ide

I think by default visual studio does keep your files/tabs open for a specific solution that you are working on even after you've closed it, however, I must have done something to change that.

P.S. I am not talking about preview tabs

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Solve problem for me and delete .suo file

[image: Reopen]